# d3.js : create an expanding list viz using selection.on

Tags: d3.js

I have a data structure like

```
[
    {"name":"foo", "links":["a", "b", "c"]}, 
    {"name":"bar", "links":["d", "e", "f"]}
]
```

I'd like to make a list like

```
<ul>
    <li> foo </li>
    <li> bar </li>
</ul>
```

which, when I click on foo, expands like

```
<ul>
    <li> foo 
        <ul>
            <li> a </li>
            <li> b </li>
            <li> c </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li> bar </li>
</ul>
```

I'd like to do this using d3.js. It's easy and fun to make the top list:

```
toplist = d3.select("body").append("ul");
toplist.selectAll("li")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("li")
        .text(function(d){return d.name;})
```

It's even easy to add the sublists:

```
items = toplist.append("ul")
    .selectAll("li")
    .data(function(d){return d.links})
    .enter()
    .append("li")
         .text(function(d){return d})
```

I can add an `on("click"..` to each `li` in `toplist`, like

```
toplist.selectAll("li")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("li")
        .text(function(d){return d.name;})
        .on("click", expand)
```

and move the sublist code into a function called expand. It looks like

```
function expand(d,i){
```

and then has the above `items = ...` code in it.

The trouble is that this then expands both `foo` and `bar` at the same time.

How do I give the `foo` list element a separate on click event to `bar` which expands only that element? Essentially, I need to pass `expand` the index of the data element, and have it only operate on that specific piece of the DOM.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I should add that if I console.log d, i, this and d3.event in the expand function I only see the element I clicked on

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have everything you need when `expand` is called. The `this` context is the li element that was clicked, and `d` is the associated data. If you only want to expand (rather than toggle between expand and collapse), then you can create the sublist by selecting this:

```
function expand(d) {
  d3.select(this)
      .on("click", null)
    .append("ul")
    .selectAll("li")
      .data(d.links)
    .enter().append("li")
      .text(function(d) { return d; });
}
```

Note that `expand` also removes the click handler from the clicked item; you don't want to add the list again when clicking twice.

If you want to toggle between expand and remove, then you need to track some state: whether the submenu is open or closed. You could either do this by storing a boolean on `d` (`d.open`, say), or you could do it by querying the DOM to see if the submenu already exists: `d3.select(this).select("ul").empty()`.

Yet another way you could do this would be to create all the submenus ahead of time, and then just toggle the visibility via the `display` style property. That's the simplest option if you have all of the data available; I'd probably only bother will creating the submenu dynamically if you were loading the link data asynchronously.

Live example: http://bl.ocks.org/1541816